# show thumb image until the actual image gets loaded using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show images like google search images.like when someone click on a particular image the thumb image get load first until the actual image get loaded,when the the actual image gets loaded the thumb is replaced by the actual image.

Please help me.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thnx Faisal for your comment,I have a gallery section where all thumb images are listed,now I want to show the actual image like google search image result.....like clicking on a particular image the thumb image will show until the actual image gets loaded. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

First you must know if you image is already loaded than you will replace it.

```
   $('img.mustLoad').on('load',function(){
         /* Fire your image resize  or thumb replacement code here */
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Tamer for your reply,but here my problem is the THUMB REPLACEMENT code onclick event as I am new in this field....is there any jquery plugin available????I got some plugins but all of them are talking about the design....please help...thanks once again Tamer

Comment: could you please explain more what you mean by onclick event ? you mean you want to do the replacement after clicking the Thumb ?

Comment: yes absolutely....suppose your are searching an image on google....you get lots of image....now when you click(click event) on a particular image,you have noticed that the first the gets blur for a moment and then few seconds later it gets clear image......
here google first show you the thumb image untill the actual image gets loaded....I hope you have noticed that at the time of loading I mean when the thumb image will show up and its get blur,you can see a  thin  loader at the bottom of that blur image.............thanx

Comment: you can use this <img src="foo.jpg" onload="hideLoadDiv();" />

Comment: I am following this tutorial where I want to show the thumb image untill the actual image gets loaded...........
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/